# Javascript Div Element Issue

Tags: javascript, html, web, scripting

OK so I have a bunch of HTML div classes and one ID containing all of the classes. I need get this same concept working in a Javascript that would produce an identical result. Any help would be greatly appreciated :). My main issue as that I cannot get the JavaScript code I've written to display the CSS in the same way as the HTML I have written.

HTML:

```
<body>

<div id = "barOne">
<div class = standard> 
<p> Magazine </p>
</div>
<div class = standard>
<p> Newspaper </p>
</div>
<div class = standard>
<p> English </p>
</div>
<div class = standard>
<p> Friends </p>
</div>
<div class = standard>
<p> Photos </p>
</div>
<div class = standard>
<p> Videos </p>
</div>
<div class = standard>
<p> Admin </p>
</div>
</div> <!-- End barOne-->

</body>
```

Here's my attempt at turning the code into a JavaScript, any ideas on what I'm missing?

```
function mainMenuBar() {
console.log("Mainmenubar invoked...");

var menuBarWrapper = document.createElement("div");
var btns = [];
var btnTxt = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
btns.push(document.createElement("div"));//Adds a button
btnTxt.push(document.createElement("p"));//Adds a p tag

btns[i].className = "standard";
btns[i].id = "btn" + i;
//btns[i].setActive("onclick","clickFunction()");
//btnTxt[i].className = "";


btns[i].appendChild(btnTxt);//Adds the lbl to button
menuBarWrapper.appendChild(btnTxt[i]);

}
document.getElementById("document.body").appendChild(menuBarWrapper);
}
function clickFunction() {
console.log("clickFunc invoked");
}
```

And here's the CSS I want to correspond to the JavaScript code that currently renders with the HTML code shown above...

```
body{
background-color: f5f5f5;   
}
.canvasGeneral {
height: 768px;
width: 1024px;
position:fixed;
left:50%;
background-color: f5f5f5;
height:768px;
/*overflow:hidden;*/
}

#barOne {
border-top: 1px solid #939393; 
left: 0px;
width: 1024px;
bottom: 1px;
height 39px; 
position:absolute;
padding-left: 35px;
/*Quick nav bar at the bottom, primary nav*/
}

.standard {
margin: 9px; 
background-color:f5f5f5;
-moz-border-radius:4px;
-webkit-border-radius:4px;
border-radius:4px;
display:inline-block;
color: #939393;
font-family:helvetica;
font-size:13px;
font-weight:light;
padding:0px 33px;
text-decoration:none;
 -webkit-transition: 0 .2s;
   -moz-transition: 0s .2s;
    -ms-transition: 0 .2s;
     -o-transition: 0 .2s;
        transition: 0 .2s;
}
.standard:active {
position:relative;
color: #007bff;
 -webkit-transition: none;
   -moz-transition: none;
    -ms-transition: none;
     -o-transition: none;
        transition: none;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert HTML Divs to Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534354/convert-html-divs-to-javascript)

Comment: in your html template you don't have any span elements and your div elements have no ids so... what are you trying to do with the script is differ from html template that you provide

Comment: The `span`s seems to be created dynamically, but I can't see the `#canvas` element exists, it's not in the example... Also it's always better to enclose attribute values within the quotes.

Comment: If the `#canvas` exists, and is an HTMLCanvasElement,  the docs of the [`canvas`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas) says: "`Permitted content: Transparent but with no interactive content descendants except for <a> elements, <button> elements, <input> elements whose type attribute is checkbox, radio, or button.`". This `setActive()`, if you're using some library, please mention it in the question, or at least tag it.

Comment: @Teemu : no specific library is being used; generic Javascript. I've edited the document so it has <p> instead of <span> that was a mistake. With my current code I've written in JS I'm just looking for a good way to replicate my HTML code using the same class names and ID name, if you can present that that would be very helpful :)

Comment: @Givi: I've edited to it to correspond better, sorry about the confusion

Comment: @brencode OK? At this line: `btns[i].appendChild(btnTxt);` you're trying to append an array to the `btns[i]`, it should be `btns[i].appendChild(btnTxt[i]);`. Also `setActive()` is _not_ a native DOM method in the HTMLDivElement, so you can't invoke it where your'e trying to invoke it now. Also `#canvas` must exist before trying to append an element to it... Your code will work, if you fix the above said line, comment the line using `setActive()` out and replace `#canvas` with `document.body`.

Comment: You can see [the code working](http://jsfiddle.net/ZCZ56/) with the fixes. If you remove the comment mark from `setActive()` line, you can see an error in the console: "`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'setActive`" (Chrome). Also if you're really appending these elements in to a `canvas` element, the `innerHTML` of the `canvas` is shown only, if the browser doesn't support `canvas` element. You need to use [`CanvasRenderingContext2D`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D) object to achieve what you want.

Comment: OK so I made the fixes to my code in DreamWeaver, but the issue is I need the code to correspond to the following CSS classes I've created, which include .standard{} and .barOne{}

Comment: Did you check the fiddle I linked in the comment above, it looks to me, that those classes are there in the `innerHTML` (I just forgot the `.oneBar` from the fixes). Though you can achieve this with a simple CSS selector: `.oneBar div {..}`, and you wouldn't need a `.standard` at all. This is probably what Th3BFG tried to tell you...

Comment: *I've also made the fixes to the code presented above

Comment: I'm sorry, I have a typo in my previous comment, the CSS selector should be `#onBar div {..}`. So, if you've made the fixes, what's the problem you still having?

Comment: Oh just checked the fiddle, thanks for the help on that. So could you show me in a answer with all the edits to my code how I would get it to correlate with my currents CSS if I edited my CSS and JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here's the code:

```
console.log("Mainmenubar invoked...");

var menuBarWrapper = document.createElement("div");
    menuBarWrapper.id = 'barOne';
var btns = [];
var btnTxt = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    btns.push(document.createElement("div"));//Adds a button
    btnTxt.push(document.createElement("p"));//Adds a p tag
    btnTxt[i].innerHTML = 'button ' + i; // Added this line just to show the element
    btns[i].id = "btn" + i;
    btns[i].addEventListener("click", clickFunction);

    btns[i].appendChild(btnTxt[i]);//Adds the lbl to button
    menuBarWrapper.appendChild(btns[i]);

}
document.body.appendChild(menuBarWrapper);
console.log(document.body.innerHTML);

function clickFunction() {
    console.log("clickFunc invoked");
}
```

Then just replace the `.standard` selector with `#oneBar div` and `.standard:active` with `#oneBar div:active`.

[A demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZCZ56/1/).

Comment: Thanks man! That JS fiddle really helped demonstrate what I was looking for :) Question answered

Answer (score 1):

Can you post what fails? Are you missing the class names for each of your divs? Did it insert the divs at all?

You are kind of doing something that doesn't make sense though. Each div creates a block, since all of the nested divs have the same class and the outer class surrounds all of them, why not just combine the two classes and have one div block or each separate div block. Is there a reason as to why you did it this way?

Comment: I'm doing it specifically this way because I have 6 buttons on a toolbar, if you can show me a better code example I would gladly reform my code based off of that

Comment: mainMenuBar() is supposed to correspond to barOne

Comment: Well, first things first, your MenuItem divs can be removed and the class applied to the `<p>`. Divs block your code, paragraphs are already blocked. This would just make it easier to read.

If you change your logic to match that, it may be easier to debug.

Comment: Each div with the p tag is in place because each div is a button on the toolbar . Can you show me an example of what you're asking me to do to my HTML code?

Comment: Or are you speaking about my javascript?

Comment: The code fais to render the CSS I have corresponding to it when I run the code

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this...
[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/zGygC/4/)

Made some changes into your code...

**Edited!**

```
function mainMenuBar() {
    console.log("Mainmenubar invoked...");

    var menuBarWrapper = document.createElement("div"),
        text = ["Magazine", "Newspaper", "English", "Friends", "Photos", "Videos", "Admin"],
        ele = null,
        i = 0;

    menuBarWrapper.id = "barOne";

    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        ele = document.createElement("div");
        ele.className = "standard";
        ele.id = "btn" + i;
        ele.innerHTML = "<p>" + text[i] + "</p>";
        menuBarWrapper.appendChild(ele);
    }
    // instead of adding event listener per element would be better if you use event delegation
    menuBarWrapper.addEventListener("click", clickFunction, false); 
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(menuBarWrapper);
}

function clickFunction(e) {
    if (e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'p') {
        console.log("clickFunc invoked");
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}

mainMenuBar();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, can you show me with some edits how to get the javascript code to correspond with some new CSS code I've added to the post?

Comment: @brencode What changes do you mean? Your CSS would work as it should on newly added elements... and maybe you want to add "barOne" id on menuBarWrapper div?

Comment: For some reason after I made the edits the CSS wont' display with the current JavaScript I have

Comment: Laying things as I have them currently, I want to have the JS work with the class standard, and the id barOne, but the current JS doesn't seem to make the CSS display

Comment: I think that's what I'm going for.. I"m awfully confused now, can you post a javascript that works without the need for edits to it with my CSS, I'm kinda lost because I'm receiving a lot of recommended edits and I'm not sure which to take..

Comment: I want to append the elements to barOne not Canvas

Comment: and do I just stick this in a script tag in my body of my page?

Comment: Please guys, tell me about this `setActive()` method, I've never seen it before, it's causing an error where ever I try to put it, but you all seem to use like it was working.

Comment: @brencode So what browser do you use??? if IE  this code should work perfectly...

Comment: @Givi I tested OP's code with IE10, the same result as with Chrome, i.e. `SCRIPT16389: Function is not valid.`, or nearby that (translated from finnish). Anyway, `setActive()` is rather for focusing the element, not for attaching event handlers.